# Use of the word sat vs sitting

Tags: word-usage

Please help resolve a dispute between my partner and me.

The other day, I sent my partner a text explains that 'I would rather be sat in the pub drinking a beer' to which I was corrected that I should have used 'sitting' instead of 'sat'. I'm pretty sure both are proper English but she disagrees and says using 'sat' is lazy. Help!

Comment: "Be sat" is correct if you are one year old and were plunked down in a high chair.

Comment: They mean different things (and more trickily, the word *be* means different things in these contexts) but I can't understand how one would be 'lazy'!

Comment: Where are you from? In parts of north England, for example, people do use the expression *was sat* instead of *was sitting*.  "I'd rather sat" and "I'd rather be sat" is perhaps considered dialectal. This is only comment because I do not know enough to write a full answer, so bear that in mind.

Comment: It's'between my partner and *me*,' although I know that isn't what you were asking. ;)

Comment: related: 1. [Is “I am sat” bad English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18609/is-i-am-sat-bad-english) 2. [I was sat thinking why you were stood there...](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106313/i-was-sat-thinking-why-you-were-stood-there-before-i-was-took-away-by-the-word-p)

Comment: Also: 3. [Using “I had rather” instead of “I would rather”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128558/using-i-had-rather-instead-of-i-would-rather) 4. [Imperative followed by “rather than”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114510/imperative-followed-by-rather-than)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is 'I would rather...' without an infinitive immediately following it correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73891/is-i-would-rather-without-an-infinitive-immediately-following-it-correct)

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for "I would rather be seated in the pub ..."

Comment: Whether this is considered correct or incorrect depends at least partially on one's views on the acceptability of dialect.

Answer (score 1):

'Be sitting' probably matches your intention. 'Be sat,' although awkward, could imply someone physically forced you to sit there.

Comment: Hmm, but what other ways can the active voice be removed from the sentence *"I would rather be sitting in the pub drinking a beer"*?

Comment: Or that is where the maitre d told you to sit.